# C Mysql driver in C++: Fetch field only (function returns mixed type)

Tags: c++, mysql, c, types

I'm trying to implement fetching data function from mysql just for one field instead whole row.

```
    auto FetchField(char *value, MYSQL_FIELD *field) {
        if (value == NULL) {
            return nullptr;
        }
        switch(field->type) {
            case MYSQL_TYPE_FLOAT:
            case MYSQL_TYPE_DOUBLE:
                return atof(value);
            case MYSQL_TYPE_LONG:
            case MYSQL_TYPE_TINY:
            case MYSQL_TYPE_INT24:
                return atoi(value);
            default:
                return value;
        }
    }
```

And usage function:

```
   auto QueryField(MYSQL *db, const char *query, ...) {
        va_list params;
        va_start(params, query);
        StmtExec(db, query, params); // this calls mysql_query with params
        va_end(params);
        MYSQL_RES *res = mysql_store_result(db);
        MYSQL_ROW row = mysql_fetch_row(res);
        return FetchField(row[0], mysql_fetch_field(res));
    }
```

So it shows error: `deduced return type "double" conflicts with previously deduced type "std::nullptr_t"`

1. I'd like avoid using `mysql_fetch_row` but how can I do it in other way? Just fetch one field instead of whole row.
2. I'd like my function will return automatic type or something like that (I know C++ has strict typing but maybe there's some way to implement it). Because now I'm doing there same (without defining datatype structs schema explicitly using `nlohmann::json` container).

```
    nlohmann::json FetchRow(MYSQL_RES *res) {
        int fields_count = mysql_num_fields(res);
        MYSQL_ROW row = mysql_fetch_row(res);
        nlohmann::json row_json;

        mysql_field_seek(res, 0);
        for(int j=0; j<fields_count; j++)
        {
            MYSQL_FIELD *field = mysql_fetch_field(res);
            if (row[j] == NULL) {
                row_json[field->name] = nullptr;
                continue;
            }
            switch(field->type) {
                case MYSQL_TYPE_FLOAT:
                case MYSQL_TYPE_DOUBLE:
                    row_json[field->name] = atof(row[j]);
                    break;
                case MYSQL_TYPE_LONG:
                case MYSQL_TYPE_TINY:
                case MYSQL_TYPE_INT24:
                    row_json[field->name] = atoi(row[j]);
                    break;
                default:
                    row_json[field->name] = row[j];
                    break;
            }
        }
        return row_json;
    }
```

So I'd like to also reuse this method from `FetchRow` method as well if that's possible.

The point why I use C driver instead of C++ because I simply don't need to use classes and OOP in my project.

Is there any other way to implement what I want?

Thanks

Comment: _without defining datatype structs schema explicitly using `nlohmann::json` container_. Have you had a look onto its code? [json.hpp](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/blob/develop/include/nlohmann/json.hpp) To me, it appears like the "big brother" of [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

Comment: @Scheff I didn't know there's `std::variant`. It's definitely answer to my question! I actually took `nlohmann::json` and it works fine for me as well